# Angular+Firebase - Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, on a simple $http request

Tags: angularjs, google-api, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to use Firebase with Angular to get a user's Access-Token, in order to retrieve his contact list later on with a $http.get request to google's API.

the first part is doing well, a popup shows, and the auth copmletes, so i'm getting the auth object with the right access-token.

this function fires when the users clicks the "Login with Google" button:

```
angular.module('myApp.gtest', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://*myfirebaseappurl*.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}])

.controller('gtestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$firebaseAuth', 'Auth', function($scope, $http, $firebaseAuth, Auth) {
    ...
    var onAuthCallback = function(authData) {
        if (authData === null) {
            console.log("onAuth fired with null data.");
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("onAuth fired, with authData = ", authData);
            refreshContacts(authData);
        }
    }

    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.deauth = $scope.auth.$onAuth(onAuthCallback);


    var refreshContacts = function(authData) {
    console.log("Refreshin contacts, with authData:", authData);
    $scope.curUserName = authData.google.displayName;
    $http.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + authData.google.accessToken + "&max-results=800&v=3.0", {})
        .then(
            function successCallback(res) {
                console.log("on auth: ", res);
                var arr = res['data']['feed']['entry'];
                $scope.availableContacts = arr.length;
                var contacts = [];
                for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                    if (!arr[i] || !arr[i]['gd$email'] || !arr[i]['gd$email'][0]['address'])
                        continue;
                    contact = {
                        name: arr[i]['title']['$t'],
                        email: arr[i]['gd$email'][0]['address']
                    };
                    contacts.push(contact);
                }
                $scope.contacts = contacts;
                $scope.statusMsg = contacts.length + " / " + arr.length + " Contacts loaded!";
            },
            function errorCallback(res) {
                $scope.statusMsg = "Error loading contacts.";
                console.log("google auth error: ", JSON.stringify(res));
            });
    };
    ...
});
```

the refresh contacts just updates $scope.contacts with the user's contact. the refresh to the page itself is made through angular two-way binding.

when i'm testing this on http://127.0.0.1:8080 using http-server, or when deploying to firebase's hosting, i'm getting the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin.json?alt=json&access_token=*****MY ACCESS TOKEN HERE******&max-results=800&v=3.0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have followed the tutorial on Firebase and added http://127.0.0.1:8080 to google developers console where needed...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Workaround : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Thanks friend, i'll try it out for development, but i'm seeking for a permanent solution - i want other user to be able to use my app without forcing them to install a chrome app, and also i want it to be available from mobile...

Comment: Which web server you are using?

Comment: For allowing CORS, try to set the below header values, with node.js + express server , it is something like this.

app.options(/\.*/, function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT');
        res.send(200);
    });
where app is var app = express();

Comment: Try this $http.jsonp('http://www.example.com?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success (function(data, ...) {
    //your data here
    ...
  })  Instead of $http.get